# Menubar icons being cut off

Tags: macos, menu-bar

For quite some time I've been having a few problems with menubar icons. Specifically long ones being cut off.

Here the Adobe Icon and the play icon (for an app called Bee) are being cut off

[image: Adobe Icon and Bee Icon being cut off]

What the play icon should act like:
http://www.neat.io/bee/docs/the-short-list.html

I am running Yosemite.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this happen for just the Bee icon with any other icon or Adobe with any other icon or any other icon with any other icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Apple does not provide tools, I would suggest the [Bartender app](http://www.macbartender.com/) to organize your menu bar.

```
Organize your menu bar apps

    Lets you tidy your menu bar apps how you want.
    See your menu bar apps when you want.
    Hide the apps you need to run, but do not need to see.
    Have the clean looking menu bar you want.
    Rearrange your menu bar items as you wish.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, used it and it fixed the adobe icon but not the bee one, so perhaps that is a bug on the developers side.

Comment: I do not know, it is possible the problem is on they site.

Comment: It looks to me like it has not been given proper space in the menu bar, try moving it or remove some other menu bar items.